# Can you help identify the insignia and the country of origin of this uniform?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

Can you help identify the insignia and the country of origin with this uniform?

[image: Man standing in uniform with mustache, hand resting on a seated woman]

Comment: How did you come by the picture? What do you know about it?

Comment: Adding a higher resolution image of the collar patches ("Kragenspiegel") would likely be helpful. The patches *appear* to depict a small twig with a pair of oak leaves, but it is difficult to say for sure.

Comment: Do you know anything about the time period during which this picture was taken? The style of the mustache *suggests* very roughly 1880-1910 to me.

Comment: @njuffa Agreed on most aspects. But surely it _is_ oak leaves. But this style might indicate: German (perhaps _not_ Austrian?), and after Kaiser even (Freikorps?)? But the litevka/rock looks much later than 1880 as well. Still a more hi-res collar pic would help. But: the lower leg part is interesting! If better pic can be made, plz make another for the part below the knees. Also, Heidi: please add all relevant info for this pic, like eg also lettering on back etc… Welcome to [History:SE](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3988/), please take a [tour] & check out [help]!

Comment: @LangLangC I suggested adding a higher resolution scan of the collar patches because confusingly, the closest visual match for these collar patches is SA-Oberführer.

Comment: @njuffa Almost. That would be really late for this visual. But look for pics of "eichenlaub kragenspiegel 1wk" (first img on general GG search,  4th on image.google, for me.

Comment: @LangLangC That does look like a good match; good sleuthing. I had searched for images of complete patches.

Comment: @njuffa Do you have access to Charles Woolley _German Uniforms_ or Carlos Jurado _German Freikorps 1918–1923_ or the like? These seem to have enough pics to approximate this. The apparent lack of shoulder (or any other) decorations confuses me, as does the puttee (or even socks) leg cloth. The pockets look like a rare variant on his tunic. Drags this still further into 18–23 area. Any counter args to that? Interested to take the A? Or favour a CW?

Comment: @LangLangC No, I don't have access to these books. I have wondered about the pockets, too. Another confusing detail. Definitely too little solid info yet for an answer from *me*.